# Extracting kafka console output as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka

I have written a consumer program to print out the message in the topic to console. But I need it as a variable to take it and use it.

My program is as follows:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('track_id',bootstrap_servers='localhost:9099')

for msg in consumer:
    x = msg.value.decode()
    print(x)
```

How can I take the output printed to console and use it as a variable in my program?

Comment: you already have the variable, it is `x`, unless I am not understanding the question

Comment: if I try to print the variable outside the for loop nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this workaround:

```
for msg in consumer:
    x = msg.value.decode()
    f = open('track.txt','w')
    print(x, file=f)
    exit()
```